# display UIView when click button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have superclass UIView. And i have button to show another View. How to show another View when click a button event. I searched docs, but i didn't get solution.

```
- (void)note:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"Note");

    vc=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 568)];

    [self.view addSubview:vc];

}
```

Comment: you want to show a view or a create a new view. what is your requirement,

Comment: I want create new view.

Comment: in this code, what problem is coming?

Comment: self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.vc]; Try this

Comment: It's also possible the note method isn't being called.  The question is self-answered, according to the problem described.  Or maybe the self.view's bound's origin is offset from CGPoint {0,0}, or maybe it's self.view is a scrollview that's been scrolled beyond 0,0,320,568.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code as it is just chane the background color of your newely create view and check it.

```
- (void)note:(id)sender{

        NSLog(@"Note");

        vc=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 568)];

        vc.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

        [self.view addSubview:vc];

    }
```

try this code..

Comment: then what's the problem of your original code?

Comment: vc.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor]; this is problem

Comment: no this is not problem your view is created.

Comment: @user2807197 This SO question seems self-answered, you may earn more down-votes unless you provide more clarity to what you're having problems with.

Comment: @TomPace He simply didn't see his new UIView because it was transparent. That was the only problem he had.

Comment: @MarcMosby It seems likely.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to try to help.  First thing: your example code is demonstrating a perfect answer to your question already, it creates and shows a view which is what you're asking for.

However, your example code is using "vc" which I am assuming is short for "view controller" as in UIViewController.  And the code in your example doesn't declare it first, so I'm guessing it's an instance variable (ivar) in your class.

So if that's correct (and I may be totally wrong), then the solution is more like:

```
- (void)note:(id)sender{


    // Load a view con
    NSString *nibfilenamewithoutextension = @"MyAwesomeViewControllerLayoutNib";
    vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibfilenamewithoutextension bundle:nil];

    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];

}
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** this is crossing the line of child view controllers and not including the full proper code for handling child view controllers. There is also the option of presenting a view controller.  Please see the following:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html